# Scroll function to change css attribute only works the second time

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

The code below is working, all except for `$('.greeting')`, it's a string of text that is normally right below `$('.userAlias')`.

When `$('#header_lower')` height is decreased, I am trying to calculate the

width of `$('.userAlias') //because its different based on username`

and assign that value to `$('.greeting').css("left")` and put it on the same line.

It fails to do it on the first scroll.  However, when I scroll back up, and then scroll back down, it then starts working until the page is reloaded.  Then it fails the first time.

The weird thing is, if I inspect the element, even on the first scroll it shows the value of left changing as it should.  It just doesn't have any effect.  Any help is much appreciated.

## JS:

```
function scrollNav() {
    var scrollState  = 'top' ;


    $( window ).scroll( function() {

        var scrollPos  = $( window ).scrollTop() ;
        var nameWidth  = $( '.userAlias' ).width() ;
        var withMargin = +nameWidth + +25 ;

        if( ( scrollPos  != 0 ) && ( scrollState === 'top' ) ) {

            $( '#wrapper' ).stop().css( {
                "padding-top" : "210px"
            } ) ;

            $( '.subHead-iconText' ).stop().animate( {
                fontSize : "00px"
            } , 100 ) ;

            $( '.subHead-icon' ).stop().animate( {
                fontSize : "40px"      ,
                margin   : "15px 25px"
            } , 100 ) ;

            $( '.greeting' ).stop().css( {
                "float"      : "left"     ,
                "display"    : "inline"   ,
                "left"       : withMargin ,
                "margin-top" : "-55px"
            } ) ;

            $( '.userAlias'    ).delay( 900 ).stop().animate( { fontSize   : '40px' , marginTop : '10px' } , 100 ).css( { "font-weight" : "normal" } ) ;
            $( '#header_lower' ).delay( 900 ).stop().animate( { height     : '70px'  } , 500 ) ;

            scrollState = 'scrolled' ;
```

## CSS:

```
.userAlias {
    height:                 69px ;

    font-size:              50px ;
    font-weight:            bold ;

    text-align:             left ;
}
.greeting {
    height:                 33px ;

    font-size:              26px ;
    font-weight:            normal ;

    text-align:             left ;
}
```

Here is fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ETHER34L/0f7exmdg/

## Solved Below

Comment: Can you provide a working example that demonstrates this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, no prob.  I will throw a fiddle together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're setting the `position` to `relative` only when you scroll it back to the top using this condition

```
else if ((scrollPos === 0) && (scrollState === 'scrolled')) {
    $('.greeting').fadeOut(100,
    function () {
        $(this).css({
            "position": "relative",
            "float": "none",
            "display": "block",
            "left": "0px",
            "margin-top": "00px"
        })
    ...
```

but not when you first scroll it down here

```
if ((scrollPos != 0) && (scrollState === 'top')) {
    $('.greeting').stop().css({
        "float": "left",
        "display": "inline",
        "left": withMargin,
        "margin-top": "-55px"
    });
    ...
```

this cause your first scroll down not to take effect like you want because on the first scroll down, the `.greeting` div doesn't have a style `position: relative` that makes your style `left: ...px` not working.

> position: static;
>   HTML elements are positioned static by default.
>
> Static positioned elements are not affected by the top, bottom, left, and right properties.
>
> An element with position: static; is not positioned in any special way; it is always positioned according to the normal flow of the page:
>
> Source: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

but on the second time you scroll after you go back to top it works, because the stlye `position: relative` is still there even though you don't declare it on

```
if ((scrollPos != 0) && (scrollState === 'top')) {
```

because the `.css` jQuery function will only replace the style that's mentioned in the object (or add it if the style is not there yet) and not clear all the style that's not mentioned there. So the `position: relative` style still exist from the first time you scroll <strike>down</strike> back to top.

What you need is just add the `"position": "relative",` when you change to state `scrolled` like in this modified [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0f7exmdg/1/), or add the `position: relative` altogether in the `CSS`

### Note:

You also use more style than needed to achieve the same results. The style that you need to get the same result is just:

```
"position": "relative",
"left": "0px",
"margin-top": "0px"
```

No need to add `float: left` and `display: inline;` or `display: block;`

Comment: You rock.  Immediately fixed my issue.  Thanks for the tip on the redundant styling